# Fill combobox with database, starting with blank item

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a combobox that is filled with this db statement:

```
select ' ' as usr_entrada, null as No_Servicio union select usr_entrada,  No_Servicio from Telemarketing where Id_Sucursal='cordoba'
```

Here the combobox is filled with a blank item before the true data, and the statement works perfectly, this is the result:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| usr_entrada  | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
|              | NULL        |
+--------------+-------------+
| CAPTURA-TMK  | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| SUP          | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TCA02TMK     | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TCACONTABAUX | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TMKCBA01     | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+`
```

The issue is that, when I fill the combobox, for some reason it erases the blank item, and I don't understand why. This is my method to fill the combobox:

```
void llenaUsuarios()
{
     Conexion con = new Conexion();
     DataTable dt=new DataTable();
     using (con.getcon())
     {
          const string sql = "select ' ' as usr_entrada, null as no_servicio union select usr_entrada,  No_Servicio from Telemarketing where Id_Sucursal=@Sucursal";
          using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql, con.getcon()))
          {
               SqlDataReader rd;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sucursal", cveSucursal);
               rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if (rd.HasRows)
               {
                   rd.Read();
                   dt.Load(rd);
                   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "usr_entrada";
                   comboBox1.ValueMember = "no_servicio";
                   comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? The sql statement is not the problem, I have another combobox filled that way and it works just fine.

Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: You are setting the DataSource of the comboBox1 to your DataTable, which doesn't contain the blank space. Shouldn't you add your static data to the DataTable before you read from the database?

Comment: Thank you Robert for your comment, the blank item is added in the sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to insert a blank item in the combo box at index = 0, correct?

```
//rest of your code
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;    
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", "-1")); //After filling the DataSource, insert an item in the Combobox at Index 0
```

What I have done here is to insert an item after the datasource is filled with the data from the DB. What happening in your code seems obvious to me. For more info on this, have a quick read. The article shows in Windows Forms but you'll get the idea in case you are on asp.net

[Adding and Removing Items from a Windows Forms ComboBox, ListBox, or CheckedListBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Last time I worked on these controls was almost a decade ago. I'm typing a sample here in SO, taking a reference from my old Source Control repo.

**Common Variables**

```
DataRow rw;
public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
public SqlDataReader dr;
public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
public SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

**Using DataTable**

```
//If DataSet contains the table already, remove it first
if (ds.Tables.Contains(tbl)) 
      ds.Tables.Remove(tbl);

//Open connection here. Better with using
  cmd.CommandText = "YOUR_SQL_QUERY_GOES_HERE";
  adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
  adp.Fill(ds, tbl);
//close the connection here

rw = ds.Tables[tbl].NewRow();        //Add a new row
rw[0] = "-1";                        //Set it's value
rw[1] = "Itemtext";                  //Set it's text
ds.Tables[tbl].Rows.InsertAt(rw, 0); //Insert this row in the DataTable(DT) at Index 0
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[tbl]; //Assign the DT in the DataSource of the combobox
comboBox1.DataTextField = "Default Text";
comboBox1.DataValueField = "Default Value";
comboBox1.DataBind();
```

**Using DataReader**

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear(); //Clear the dropdown first
//Open the connection, set SqlCommandType and Text
using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
     comboBox1.DataSource = reader; //Assign DataReader to the DataSource of the Combobox
     comboBox1.DataValueField = "usr_entrada";
     comboBox1.DataTextField = "no_servicio";
     comboBox1.DataBind();
     //Here you can insert a new item at Index 0 of the Combobox.
     //For your case, keep the "Default Text" blank
     comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Default Text--", "-1"));
  }
//close the connection
```

*Please note that the code is not optimized for production use and is only to give you more ideas! So do not penalize the answer because of the code quality. I have written it directly in SO and there might be some syntax errors!*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works fine, but I really want to know what is wrong in my code, because I have another two comboboxes filled like this (with another statement, of course) and those two works fine.

Comment: That's tricky to say! Have you set the property of those other two comboboxes to have a default item? Select any one of them, Hit F4 and check in the properties window? If you can't find anything, try this - Duplicate one of the working combobox and then try. If that works, then there is surely some properties assigned to it.